# Angular service loses set data in new controller

Tags: angularjs

I have a link that I want to use to pass data to another page. I am able to access the service on the page I go to, but the data is empty.

The HTML:

```
<a href="/signup" ng-click="saveSubscriptionData()"">Female</a>
```

The service:

```
var app = angular.module('boxHome', []);

app.controller('boxHomeController', function ($scope, SubscriptionService) {
    $scope.saveSubscriptionData = function() {
        SubscriptionService.gender = 'male';
        SubscriptionService.subscription = 'infant';
        console.log(SubscriptionService);
    }
});

app.factory('SubscriptionService', function () {
    return {
        gender: '',
        subscription: ''
    };
});
```

The above log statement returns gender: 'male' and subscription: 'infant'.

The page I link to:

```
var appSignup = angular.module('boxSignup', ['boxHome']);

appSignup.controller('boxSignupController', function ($scope, SubscriptionService) {
    $scope.init = function (domainId) {
        console.log(SubscriptionService);
    };
});
```

I expect the above log statement to return gender: 'male' and subscription: 'infant'. It returns gender: '' and subscription ''.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is your application a SPA - if not, a page reload will clear your service each time.

Comment: No it's not. How would you handle this?

Comment: Read up on angular routing, and some articles on Angular SPA tutorials. (They'll explain way better than I can) - if you don't want to go the SPA way - you'd have to store your data in local storage and get it each load.

Comment: your service is not saving the values sent by first controller. your service always return '' no matter what.

Comment: @Pradeepb It is saved in the saveSubscriptionData() function on ng-click.

Comment: `app.factory('SubscriptionService', function () {
    return {
        gender: '',
        subscription: ''
    };
});`  Where are you saving here??

Comment: @Pradeepb I am saving like this: SubscriptionService.gender = 'male';
        SubscriptionService.subscription = 'infant';

Answer (score 2):

```
app.service('SubscriptionService',function(){
   var gender='';
   var subscription='';
   this.save=function(gender,subscription){        
      this.gender=gender;
      this.subscription=subscription;
   };

   this.getGender=function(){
      return gender; 
   };

   this.getSubscription=function(){
      return subscription;
   };
}); 


.controller('boxHomeController', function ($scope, SubscriptionService) {
    $scope.saveSubscriptionData = function() {
        SubscriptionService.save('male','infant');
    }
 });
```

Comment: No luck. The SubscriptionService still returns empty strings.

Comment: That's May be because  you are using 2 angular-modules. `appSignup` and `app`.

Comment: Yes, I need to be able to use the data between both apps.

Comment: 2 apps? Or 2 views? In the question you have mentioned is 'from one page to another '.

Comment: Two ng-apps. I just need to pass data to another page on my site.

Comment: You are doing it wrong then between two application, you can't share like this. Use `localstorage`

Answer (score 0):

You are returning new instances of the JSON object with each call to the factory and thus not sharing state. To fix this, declare an object inside the factory that gets returned instead:

```
app.factory('SubscriptionService', function () {
    var service = {};

    var info = {};
    info.gender = '';
    info.subscription = '';

    service.getInfo = getInfo;

    function getInfo(){
        return info;
    }

    return service;
});
```

When you use it:

```
var info = SubscriptionService.getInfo();
console.log(info.subscription);
```